Keras Attention layer not returning attention scores
I'm using keras=3.7.0 and trying to implement a custom Temporal Convolutional Attention Network (TCAN) block. While the Attention layer works in a standalone test case, I encounter an issue when integrating it into my custom model. Specifically, the error occurs when I attempt to unpack the output of the Attention layer.
The following works:

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Attention, Input

# Example inputs
batch_size, time_steps, features = 2, 8, 16
query = tf.random.uniform((batch_size, time_steps, features))
value = tf.random.uniform((batch_size, time_steps, features))
key = tf.random.uniform((batch_size, time_steps, features))

# Attention layer with return_attention_scores=True
attention_layer = Attention(use_scale=True, dropout=0.1)
output, attention_scores = attention_layer(
    [query, value, key], return_attention_scores=True, use_causal_mask=True
)

print(f"Output shape: {output.shape}")
print(f"Attention scores shape: {attention_scores.shape}")


Gives:
Output shape: (2, 8, 16)
Attention scores shape: (2, 8, 8)

Why is it not working in my main code?
def tcan_block(inputs, filters, kernel_size, activation, dilation_rate, d_k, atn_dropout):
    """
    A single block of TCAN.
    Arguments:
        inputs: Tensor, input sequence.
        filters: Integer, number of filters for the convolution.
        kernel_size: Integer, size of the convolution kernel.
        dilation_rate: Integer, dilation rate for the convolution.
        d_k: Integer, dimensionality of the attention keys/queries.
    Returns:
        Tensor, output of the TCAN block.
    """
    # Temporal Attention
    query = Dense(d_k)(inputs)
    key = Dense(d_k)(inputs)
    value = Dense(d_k)(inputs)

    # Apply Keras Attention with causal masking
    attention_output, attention_scores = Attention(use_scale=True, dropout=atn_dropout)(
        [query, value, key],
        use_causal_mask=True,
        return_attention_scores=True,
    )

    # Dilated Convolution
    conv_output = Conv1D(
        filters, kernel_size, dilation_rate=dilation_rate, padding="causal", activation=activation
    )(attention_output)

    # Enhanced Residual
    # Calculate Mt using cumulative sum up to each time step
    importance = Lambda(lambda x: K.cumsum(x, axis=1))(attention_scores)
    enhanced_residual = Lambda(lambda x: x[0] * x[1])([inputs, importance])

    # Add residual connection
    output = Add()([inputs, conv_output, enhanced_residual])
    return output

Error:
  File "/home/furkan/Documents/Deep-Learning-Model/src/utils/models/tcan.py", line 138, in build_tcan_model
    x = tcan_block(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/furkan/Documents/Deep-Learning-Model/src/utils/models/tcan.py", line 87, in tcan_block
    attention_output, attention_scores = Attention(use_scale=True, dropout=atn_dropout)(
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/furkan/Documents/Deep-Learning-Model/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/backend/common/keras_tensor.py", line 167, in __iter__
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Iterating over a symbolic KerasTensor is not supported.

